# Optimizing Azure Storage queries for RIA services

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, wcf-ria-services

I'm working with Azure Storage Tables and RIA services to create a, rather basic, Silverlight UI to access and manage some of the data.

Nothing too fancy: a data model with some annotations, and a `DomainDataSource`, make it all a breeze.

With one minor exception.

When I have a really, really large table, then loading it, at least when I'm doing this on the Development Fabric and even using the `LoadSize` parameter of the `DomainDataSource`, takes a LOT of time.

My guess is that the following thing happens:

- The Silverlight client asks the RIA service for, say, 100 first rows of the table.
- Since Azure Data Storage queries are extremely basic, the service retrieves all the rows from the data storage, and THEN performs Take(100) on that set.
- Client gets the first 100 rows.

This is OK for conserving bandwidth, but it's far from optimal when you consider that one must pay for processing power used by an Azure-based application.

Is there any way to optimise the RIA service queries? Is it even at all possible to use `Take()` and `Skip()` methods on Azure Storage Tables?

EDIT: I am using WCF RIA Services SP1 Beta, and have followed several tutorials on Silverlight with RIA services (which are all very very similar). Combining the two, I'm simply wondering if loading a large table into Silverlight can be improved by adding the `LoadSize` parameter. At the moment it seems to conserve bandwidth only (as the correct amount of rows is being sent to the Silverlight client), but the whole process still uses as much CPU time as it does for the whole table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried RIA Services SP1 Beta? It includes TableDomainService that handles all the logic by managing entities in the specified Azure Storage account. Also, you can inspect traffic between your service and Azure Storage using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com) to find out what the problem is.

References:

- WCF RIA Services SP1 Beta [announcement](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/10/27/RiaServicesV1SP1Beta.aspx)
- Kyle McClellan's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/) - he is the person who developed TableDomainService. There are a lot of posts in his blog about this feature.

**EDIT:**
As [Kyle McClellan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373687/kyle-mcclellan) mentioned below in the comment, this problem really exists in WCF RIA Services SP1 **Beta**.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm using. Like I said, the client gets the proper amount of rows. It's just that the service itself has to get all the rows from the Storage Tables, and process them, which takes a lot of time (and eats CPU), at least on the Dev Fabric. If the same is true for deployed applications, then it's hardly optimal.

Comment: Have you checked the actual traffic between service and Azure Storage?

Comment: Yes, I did. Like I stated, the response is correct, and contains only the given number of rows. However, the time it takes to select those rows is always the same, regardless if I want 5, 100, or the whole table at once, which leads me to believe that the the entire table contents are being first "loaded" by the service and only then the Take() and Skip() operations take place. I'm concerned that this will cause a lot of CPU usage in the final, deployed application, and will thus make the whole thing a lot more expensive to run.

Comment: When I said about _actual traffic_ I meant that you should check not the service response to your Silverlight client, but the actual information that transfered between **the service** and **Azure Storage**. Probably, this kind of problems (high CPU usage) can appear on the development server, since the storage emulator uses your local SQL Server instance under the hood. You _need_ to check your traffic, to identify the exact problem.

Comment: I've used AnjLab Sql Profiler to check what kind of queries are used. Despite having specified a `LoadSize` of 10 and a `PageSize` of 5 (for a `DataPager`), there clearly is the following entry in the log: SELECT TOP 1001 *
FROM TableRow
WHERE AccountName = 'devstoreaccount1' and TableName = 'Position'.

Comment: [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com/) can inspect all HTTP traffic on your computer. It's really powerful tool with a lot of features, but basically you just need to launch it before perform request and then find your request in the Web Sessions list. You can find detailed information about fiddler on the official site.

Comment: I thought Fiddler was troublesome when it comes to localhost traffic, and I'm not sure how to get the Dev Fabric to use ipv4.fiddler instead of localhost. Anyway, like I wrote above, I've used an Sql Profiler to check the queries, and the app is clearly asking for a lot more rows than it should.

Comment: SQL Profiler's trace doesn't confirm that storage emulator returns all the records from database to your service. Storage emulator itself can filter necessary data before return it to your service. It's not efficiently, but it's just local development emulator. So, to find out the exact problem, you should check traffic between storage emulator and your service :). Moreover, internal behavior of Dev Server can differ from the real Azure Storage, so to be confident that your service works efficiently, it could be a good idea to validate it on a real Windows Azure account.

Comment: Hmm, well, Fiddler can't check what's going on on localhost or 127.0.0.1, and that's what the Dev Fabric is using. DSInit allows me to specify the SQL instance name to use, but WITHOUT the server qualifier (so I'm guessing it's also forcing localhost). Other than that, I'm not sure how to check what's precisely going on between Table Storage and my service.

Comment: The problem you've described above is exactly what's happening. RIA takes a different paging approach from Table Storage and the result is not suitable for enormous tables. It's definitely a goal of mine to improve the performance for this scenario, but it's something I couldn't get in there for the first release.There are probably workarounds, but I haven't had much time to investiage yet. Something to consider may be using a WCF Data Services client for the really large table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you retrieve all entities in code to perform the query or that the Table service has to scan all entities to return the results? In either case you are probably using Talbe storage the wrong way.

Azure Table Storage is not an RDBMS and you shouldn't treat it this way. It is designed to allow ultra-fast and scalable modifications, easy partitioning and indexed access. The only indexed access is by the partition and row key. It is definitely not suitable for ad-hoc queries and reports. In this respect it is not that different from most NoSQL databases.

I suspect you are trying to retrieve query results using ad-hoc filters and display them in a datagrid. This is an ad-hoc query/reporting scenario for which the Table Storage is not suitable.

That said, there are ways you can optimize reporting even with table storage. The most important thing is to understand that reporting data (let's consider datagrids as reports for this discussion) should be separate from transactional data - that's what [Command-Query Responsibility Separation](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/) (CQRS) is all about.

- You can use multiple tables to store the results for different reports  and update them asynchronously while processing transactions. You can use partition keys that combine multiple field values in each table that make retrieving the report's rows easier. You still have to define your reports at the server level. In this case, the scenario is closer to retrieving report snapshots rather than querying.
- You can extract the reporting data to SQL Azure and use SQL for ad-hoc reporting. Updating will have to be done asynchronously as before, but you gain ad-hoc querying. SQL Azure is much more expensive though.
- An unusual solution, suited for fairly static reports (e.g. montly or weekly summaries) is to use BLOB storage to store the report data in JSon format (or whatever suits you). You still have to define the appropriate partition and row keys. This is similar to creating report snapshots in SQL Server reporting services.

The most suitable solution depends on your specific scenario:

- If your application processes business transactions (eg. orders, phone calls etc) your main table should use keys that optimize TX processing and the report tables should use keys that optimize report retrieval.
- If you are building a forum, web site or CMS service, you probably can create one "Posts" table per forum for the posts, partitioned by threadid (just an idea) and separate "index" tables for tags, users etc that link to the posts table.

That said, Table Storage does support the OData/WCF Data Service query operators (filter etc), skip [($skip)](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#SkipSystemQueryOption) and take ([$top](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#TopSystemQueryOption)).

Comment: To be quite frank, I think what I'm trying to do (at least at this stage of implementation) is so basic, that it doesn't really fit into your answer. ;) At the moment all I have is WCF RIA Services SP1 Beta (as stated by the first answer, which is also something I failed to mention, my mistake), a table with lots of rows, and a RIA services with Silverlight as a means to create a simplistic UI to access the data. Simply put: specifying the `LoadSize` parameter doesn't improve loading times (albeit the correct amount of rows is sent to the client). As such, what could be the issue?